# How to handle SharePhoto result with Callbackmanager?

Tags: android, facebook, callback

My users are posting their photos to facebook and I want to know that. 
In the last SDK I used this code to get the callback:

```
uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode & 0xffff, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {


    @Override
    public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, final Bundle data) {


        isComplete = FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogDidComplete(data);


        for (Bitmap bitmap : images) {
            getRidOfBitmapIfneeded(bitmap);
        }

        //get rid of stored references to bitmapss
        images.clear();
        if (isComplete) {
            String completionGesture = FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogCompletionGesture(data);
            if (completionGesture == null || FacebookDialog.COMPLETION_GESTURE_CANCEL.equals(completionGesture)) {
                //Show Publish Cancel Toast
                Log.d("Facebook isComplete", "user canceled");
                setReadyToClick();


            } else {

                String id = data.getString("id");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    checkIfCanShare();



            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
        setReadyToClick();
    }
});
```

Now in their new SDK I have to use CallbackManager. I didn't find any examples and couldn't figure out how to do it properly and get the data.

Would like to have a little example :)

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: The code that was given there isn`t enough.

Comment: Our samples some examples that you can look at. [Example one](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/RPSSample/src/com/example/rps/MainActivity.java), [example two](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/example/scrumptious/SelectionFragment.java)